# Implementing an MQTT broker

Tags: java, mqtt

I am trying to implement a Java MQTT broker on top of Google Compute Engine.  My broker will  be used to handle a very large number of SUBSCRIBE and PUBLISH messages from IoT devices. So, I am planning on using the autoscaling feature to accommodate my load needs.

I am not sure which Open Source Java based MQTT broker I should use to start off my implementation. I was hoping I could get some suggestions. I am specifically looking for an open source broker that supports features such as durable subscribers, retain message, wildcards etc.

Also, since MQTT is built on TCP, could I just build my own broker from scratch that uses Java sockets and listens on a port? I am assuming the answer for this is no, but I would like to get it clarified.

Comment: What broker did you end up using?

Answer (score 7):

There is a list of broker implementations available here:

https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/servers

It should be pretty up to date, but may not include absolutely all implementations. Some of the Java based brokers include:

- HiveMQ
- Moquette
- ActiveMQ

They are not all opensource but there are several

There should be no reason why you couldn't implement your own broker, the protocol spec is here:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I am specifically looking for an open source broker that supports features like wildcards, durable subscribers etc. Do all brokers support that, or does it depend on the broker? These features are a part of the MQTT specification.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also a Mqtt broker as [vert.x](http://vertx.io/) module like [this](https://github.com/giovibal/vertx-mqtt-broker-mod).

For the second question, the answer is yes, shure.

But why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I am specifically looking for something that supports features like wildcards, durable subscribers etc. Do all brokers support that, or does it depend on the broker?